# Number of zeros of a solution of an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, roots

Consider $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ and $y$ a non-null solution of equation
\begin{equation}
y''=f(y(t)), \qquad t \in [0,1] 
\end{equation}
Prove that $y$ has just a finite number of zeros, if any. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: So we can't have $f(t)=0$ and $y=0$ such that there is an infinite amount of zeroes?

Comment: @SimpleArt We can't have that there exists an infinite number of values $t_n$ such that $y(t_n)=0$

Comment: But if $y=0$, then for all $t_n$, $y(t_n)=0$.  So my question is why can't the solution be $y=0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: Assume the contrary and use compactness to find $t_n\rightarrow t^*$ for which $y(t_n)=0$ (whence also $y(t^*)=0$). Show that 
$y'(t^*)=0$ and also $y''(t^*)=0$ and that this implies $y\equiv 0$ contradicting the hypothesis.

Comment: How do you get $y''(t_*) = 0$? I get that $y'(t_*) = 0$, but isn't $y''(t_*) = f(y(t_*)) = f(0)$?

Comment: You are on the right track. Suppose it was non-zero, say positive. Then $y''(t_*)=f(0)>0$. By continuity of $f$, $y''>0$ in a neighborhood of $t_*$ so $y$ is strictly convex  in that neighborhood. But then the zero of $y$ must be isolated. In fact imposing the diff eqn is a clever way of avoiding functions like $x^5 \sin(1/x)$ which is $C^2$ but having zeros accumulating.

Comment: Could I say that $y''(t^*)=0$ because
\begin{equation}
y''(t^*)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{y'(t_n)-y'(t^*)}{t_n-t^*}=0 \quad ?
\end{equation}

Comment: Almost. But $y'(t_n)$ need not vanish when $y(t_n)=0$. But you may use the MVT to say that between two zeros of $y$ you may find a zero of $y'$ and then argue as you do with that sequence of zeros.